# Are 2 INSERT statements guaranteed to complete sequentially?

Tags: postgresql

We've got a system that receives event from clients and stores them in a database.

Each event is saved as an atomic `INSERT`, and has an `id_event` which is an auto-incremented primary key.

Our clients can execute a specific action that causes 2 events to get fired in rapid succession:

- 1) `name: 'board-added', boardId: 12344`
- 2) `name: 'board-switched', boardId: 12344`

Both events arrive at our server in the correct order.

However, for some reason we keep finding some `board-switched` events having an `id_event` that precedes it's corresponding `board-added` event.

As you can see in the below result set, `board-added` has a higher `id_event` than `board-switched` which is wrong.

`{name: "board-switched", boardId: 313994, id_event: 48041136}
{name: "board-added", boardId: 313994, id_event: 48041137}`

My question is:

Is it possible that 2 `INSERT` events, executed sequentially will cause the 2nd `INSERT` to complete before the 1st `INSERT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not guaranteed if they are separate requests that are not in the same database transaction. Given the architecture of modern web apps, if they are separate requests I can almost guarantee that they are not in the same transaction and so are in no way dependant on each other.

A connection-pooled application is likely to accept the two requests with different threads, so even if the requests are issued by the client in order, the second request could `insert` into the database before the first if execution of the first was slower.

Comment: Ok, so what if the 2 INSERT statements are sent in the correct order to the database but are not within a transaction? Are they still subject to a race hazard?